# UIImage not showing up

Tags: iphone, ios, json, uiimage

I am parsing JSON using AFNetworking.

i passed 2 images and text from one view to another but i cant view the image on the UIImage view.

I can see the link of the images on the console.

here is my code [(link to github)](https://github.com/miznat/youtube)

```
#import "KKDetailsViewController.h"


@interface KKDetailsViewController ()

@end

@implementation KKDetailsViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.textView.text = [self.importVideoMetaData objectForKey:@"description"];

    self.imageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[(NSDictionary *)self.importThumbnail objectForKey:@"hqDefault"]];


    NSLog(@" imported thumbnail %@", self.importThumbnail);


}
```

here is the .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface KKDetailsViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSDictionary *importVideoMetaData;

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSDictionary *importThumbnail;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@end
```

Comment: Where is `importVideoMetaData` setup?

Comment: self.importVideoMetaData how are you giving this object data, can you post some code.

Comment: `imageNamed:` will return you an image that is available on your target, you cannot simply pass a url there and expect it to work...

Comment: importedThumbnail, do you have this image in your bundle?

Comment: @Rahul i am parsing JSON using AFNetworking

Comment: In viewDidLoad, if you log self.imageView what does it give you?

Answer (score 0):

ok here is how i made it work:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.textView.text = [self.importVideoMetaData objectForKey:@"description"];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[self.importThumbnail objectForKey:@"hqDefault"]];

    [self.imageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fakeThumbnail.png"]];


    NSLog(@" imported thumbnail %@", url);


}
```